# Taking only the required subset of files from a Python project to make a deployable executable?

Tags: python, deployment, organization

I have a very large ML project that includes an internal library of training, metrics, demo, etc.  Python classes I wrote. I need to make just a subset of this code deployable to edge devices. My file hierarchy looks something like this (simplified):

```
project
  -- ext (external libraries)
  -- lib (internal libraries)
     -- training
     -- inference
     -- metrics
     -- ..etc
  -- sub-project
     -- src
       -- sub-project-specific src files..
     -- bin
       -- sub-project executables here...
```

In the above, sub-projects will access internal library and external library code when needed.

I want to deploy just a single sub-project and the specific internal and external library dependencies used to a device. For eg., if the sub-project is just running inference, I don't want to include, and potentially expose to hackers, the training code on the device. This deployable solution will run an executable from the `bin` folder above.

Ideally also I don't want to create an entirely new project and repository of this subset of files to maintain and keep the code 1 to 1 with the original project as the original project is being developed. If at all possible I also want to protect the code from being readable (or at least make it harder to read) in case anyone is able to gain access to the edge device.

Is the best solution to this to just create a custom script to copy files from the original project to build a deployable project on every push to production? Then maybe just maintain a list of dependencies myself through for eg a JSON file that the builder script can parse through? After I'm thinking I could just build a Python wheel of the deployable project and deploy these to our devices? Or are there tools available to automate this for me?

Answer (score 0):

The best option to do you describe is use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). 
[Here](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) is Python Docker Official Image.

You must install docker for create and run docker images. 
The idea is envolve you ml code inside docker image (such as a virtual machine but very light) and deploy this, with a folder o port linked from main os to docker,  for send new data to the model and give the inference.

Comment: Sure, but Docker will help me with creating a deployable environment across devices. I'm looking to automate the process from development code to bare bones deployable code for the reasons listed above in my question.

Comment: Yes, you can use docker-hub put the docker image available for all devices. Also you can use iothub-azure or iot-aws ot automate this task